# How to count Badge value every time in push notification when arrived?

Tags: xcode5

How to count Badge value every time in push notification when arrived?

badge value increased by 1 every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code , delegate method to check the page value

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSDictionary *notification = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    //notification is what you want. print it to find out the details. 
    //Title, Badge Count and all that
}
```